# Problems with setbeamerfont

Tags: fonts, beamer, fontsize

I'm trying to change the size of fonts in the title of my `beamer` blocks but am getting nowhere.

Here is a link to [a ZIP file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2225877/LaTex/egu_poster.zip) containing what you should need to see… Too much code to post here. The problem is centered around line 28 of the .sty file:

```
\setbeamerfont*{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bf,size=\Huge}
```

No matter how I try to set the font size, it doesn't reflect any changes when rendering the PDF. The family and series seem to work just fine.

Using the `beamerposter` package, if that matters. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\bf` command you're using to make the font bold is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore (see [`l2tabuen.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/l2tabuen)). The reason for this can be observed here directly: It resets the font changes you made before, so the size command (which is executed before the series is set internally) can't have any effect. Use `\bfseries` instead:

```
\setbeamerfont*{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bfseries,size=\Huge}
```

And please try to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that is focused on your problem next time, i.e. something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\setbeamerfont*{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bfseries,size=\Huge}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Title}
Content
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also I don't see the need to use the starred version of the commands here.

Comment: Thanks, \bf was indeed the culprit. Sorry I didn't include a minimal working example, but whenever I try to trim out just what I need for an example it breaks. The "minimal" and "example" are the easy parts, but "working"…

@percusse: My examination of the manual has left me confused as to what difference the star makes. Could you explain?

Thanks again, everyone.