# Beamerposter scale parameter, text font size and title font size

Tags: beamer, fontsize, paper-size, beamerposter

I want to create a poster with `beamerposter` with pagesize 240cm (width) x 120cm (height) with two columns. 
Will the following line of code produce what I need?

```
\usepackage[size=custom,width=240,height=120,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
```

If  so, what does the `scale` option do? If I set it equal to `2` then will my font size and paper size double?

Secondly, I need to have the title font size of 10cm and text size of 5cm (with the title in the center).
How can I code this?

Comment: Can anybody know how to change title and text font size of the following beamerposter template: http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/beamer-poster/. I have to set height of at least 10cm for title font.

Comment: I think this post has your answer.  Check the solution. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51556/problems-with-setbeamerfont

Answer (score 11):

I am not very expert but recently I am also working with `beamer` to create a poster. 
The scale option is for your font size. Like I use

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=77,height=107,scale=1.4,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter}
```

I choose scale size 1.4, then I choose `\Large` size for my title, so it will multiply by 1.4 than the usual font size (`\Large` in `12pt` Beamer is `16.24pt`). Now you have to calculate for your's one...

You can get the font sizes in [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting).

Answer (score 3):

Scale tends to increase font, figures etc to completely fill the page. Here is something you might find useful:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.20]{beamerposter}  
\newlength{\sepwid}  
\newlength{\onecolwid}  
\newlength{\twocolwid}  
\newlength{\threecolwid}  
\setlength{\paperwidth}{240cm}  
\setlength{\paperheight}{120cm}    
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.025\paperwidth}
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.21875\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.4625\paperwidth}
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.70625\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\usetheme{confposter
```