# Text scaling for beamerposter

Tags: fontsize, scaling, beamerposter

I am making a poster for a conference using the beamerposter package.  I have made my own style file. However, I am unable do decide what would be the right scaling for the poster to be seen well. I could not even understand what is the "real" fontsize given the scale and the fact I use 12pt beamer fontsize as my basic font size.

I read the answers for the following question but could not find an answer.
[Beamerposter scale parameter, text font size and title font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53561/beamerposter-scale-parameter-text-font-size-and-title-font-size).

The relevant lines in my tex file are

```
\documentclass[final,12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{mystyle}   %The style is an adaptation of I6pd2 style
\usepackage[size=custom,width=240,height=120,scale=2]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\title{\Huge  Best Poster Ever!}
\author{Me\inst{1},- Someone else\inst{2}}
\institute{
\inst{1} INST1 \qquad
\inst{2}  INST2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock}{3.5}(0.1,3)
\begin{block}{\Large Introduction}
This is going to be a great poster, once I'll figure out the best scaling for text size!
\end{block}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and below is the content of the `beamerthemmystyle` file.

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememystyle}  % this style was created by Thomas Deselaers an Philippe Dreuw

\RequirePackage{tangocolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\mode<presentation>



\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=black,bg=taplum}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tabutter, bg=ta3gray}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\large,series=\tt}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=ta2orange}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=ta2butter}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=green}

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=ta3orange, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=blue, bg=ta3skyblue}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=taskyblue,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=taorange,bg=ta2plum}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bf}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{fg=ta2orange}

\setbeamercolor*{example body}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{example title}{bg=taorange,fg=ta2gray}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ta3gray}

%\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=taorange}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ta3skyblue}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster


\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
\vskip.75ex
\begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=1ex,center,rounded=true, shadow=true,leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
\usebeamerfont*{block title}%
%{\rule[-0.4ex]{0mm}{2ex}\insertblocktitle}%
{\strut\insertblocktitle}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
{\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
\leavevmode

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
\begin{columns}[T]
 \begin{column}{.1\paperwidth}
         \vskip3ex
         \begin{center}
        \textbf{\large LOGO}
         \end{center}
         \vskip1ex
       \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.85\paperwidth}
    \vskip1ex
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\Huge{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\LARGE{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vskip2ex
\end{beamercolorbox}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
\rule{0pt}{2pt}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
\rule{0pt}{2pt}
\end{beamercolorbox}

\leavevmode%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4ex,leftskip=1em,rightskip=1em]{author in head/foot}%
\texttt{FOOTER HERE?}
\hfill
\texttt{AND HERE?}
\vskip1ex
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip0pt%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
\rule{0pt}{2pt}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}


\mode<all>

% adapt height of imtemize rectangles
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hskip0.1em}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$\triangleright$}\hskip0.1em}
% or define your own template using \defbeamertemplate{itemize item}, see beameruserguide.pdf

% equal font sizes for all levels
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\normalsize}


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-master: "poster"
%%% End:
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If the theme you are using is not messing with font sizes, I suggest you remove the `\usetheme` line from your MWE, otherwise you should give us the content of `beamerthememystyle.sty` so that we can compile your example.

Comment: @TonioElGringo Thanks, I added the contents of the style file, otherwise the title, authors and institutes are no displayed.